# How can I fix underscan/overscan when the slider isn't shown in System Preferences on macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, display, preferences

So I have this same problem as in [How can I fix underscan/overscan when the slider isn't shown in System Preferences?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422569/how-can-i-fix-underscan-overscan-when-the-slider-isnt-shown-in-system-preferenc):

> I purchased two new monitors recently and both had pretty bad overscan (underscan? there were black bars around the screen). My mac no longer has the setting it used to have in the Displays section of System Preferences to fix this.

Unfortunately the solution presented there doesn't work any longer because  `/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics` does not exist in MacOS Monterey. Trying to find it on Mac, as well as googling around... I have found nothing.

Does anyone know where `pcsn` values are now kept? Or if there is *any* solution to manually changing underscan settings without using MacOS' GUI?

Comment: I'm using Monterey and `/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics` exists for me.

Comment: It didn't exist for me on a brand new MacBook. Has this setting been located elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

smithjw was right - found this thread by searching my problem, the solution was to hit "p size" on my monitor's remote to squish things down to fit the sceen.  HDMI image was way too big for the screen, mouse going off all four edges.  Changing monitor settings fixed it.

I'd rather do it the old way though, underscan, so I could leave the monitor setting to default, no idea what I will plug into it next time.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with the displays themselves. If you have your Mac plugged into the monitor via DisplayPort or HDMI, they will send the full picture/resolution to your monitors.

In order to resolve this, you'll need to use the buttons on the external displays to open the menu and change either the Aspect Ratio or scale.

To get more specific, if you have the model number, simply search Google for "MODEL_NUMBER overscan" or "MODEL_NUMBER aspect ratio".

Comment: Thanks, I can't do this as my monitor is an old TV and doesn't have these options. However buying a dedicated USB-C to HDMI cable worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is probably an error/bug since I was using my monitor #1 via HDMI with no problems, and then when I plugged monitor #2 into my Mac and played with the underscan/overscan slider to fit everything into monitor #2, then when I go back to the display I always use (monitor #1), it was underscanned and there was no slider to fix it!

As a mac OS Monterey user, I could not find `/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics` as well.

The problem is weirdly solved by using an HDMI-to-VGA converter and plugging my mac to monitor #1 with VGA, and then switching back to HDMI!

It probably is a bug...

Answer (score 0):

I have the save exact problem as allisknowing.  Was using 1 external monitor with my 2020 Mac Mini M1 on Monterey, and the image filled out my monitor normally.  I setup a 2nd projector monitor and found the underscan slider to make it fit the screen, but now my original monitor is not taking up the whole screen and theres no underscan to make it larger.  I hoped that ugrading to Ventura would fix it, but still the same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/329021)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this in the end by simply getting a new dedicated USB-C to HDMI cable. Then the overscan option shows up. Before that I was using a cheap USB-C to multiple output adaptor.