# Where are the overscan and underscan values stored in MacOS Monterey

Tags: terminal, display, graphics, monterey, plist

The overscan / underscan values for external displays have moved in MacOS Monterey (potentially earlier). They used to be editable in `/var/db/.com.apple.iokit.graphics`. As mentioned in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436063/how-can-i-fix-underscan-overscan-when-the-slider-isnt-shown-in-system-preferenc) (which I do not believe to be a duplicate) the values have moved.

Are these stored in an editable file in MacOS 12.4?

Comment: The other question asks "Does anyone know where pcsn values are now kept?", which basically is the same thing you ask here.

Comment: It doesnt get answered so you have been actively unhelpful. Congrats

Comment: Closing something as a duplicate doesn't mean that the question is not important. It will ensure that all answers will be in the same place though, even if people find your post first and then follow the link. I also edited the original question to bump it back to the front page, let's see whether it gathers attention.